# How to change font and color of title and alertController?

Tags: ios, swift

I'm wondering is there some way i can change font and color of title 
[image] (title itself and a back button) and alertController [image]

in swift ?

Answer (score 1):

using KVC below `code` works for me in `ios8`.

```
   UIAlertController *alertVC = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Title label" message:@"" preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleActionSheet];
    NSMutableAttributedString *hogan = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"Testing text"];
    [hogan addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName
                  value:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:50.0]
                  range:NSMakeRange(24, 11)];
    [alertVC setValue:hogan forKey:@"attributedTitle"];



    UIAlertAction *button = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Label text"
                                                     style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                                                   handler:^(UIAlertAction *action){
                                                       //add code to make something happen once tapped
                                                   }];
    UIImage *accessoryImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"someImage"];
    [button setValue:accessoryImage forKey:@"image"];
```

Answer (score 0):

In you `AppDelegate.m` set `window.tintColor` to your desired Color. **But** it only change the color of back button arrow and text.

AFAIK you can't change alerts UI contents. Try with custom alerts. There are too many Custom Alerts.